# Clarification about php and scope

Tags: php, scope

main.controller.php:

```
final class MainController extends Controller   {

    public function is_locked() {
        $lock = new View('lock');
        Res::render($lock);
    }
}
```

view.class.php:

```
final class View {

    private $data;


    public function get_title() {
        return isset($this->title) ? $this->title : DEFAULT_TITLE;
    }
    public function get_layout() {
        return isset($this->layout) ? $this->layout : 'base';
    }
    public function get_layout_path() {
        return SITE_PATH .'app/views/layouts/'. $this->get_layout() .'.layout.php';
    }
    public function get_path() {
        return SITE_PATH .'app/views/' .$this->name .'.view.php';
    }


    public function print_title() {
        echo $this->get_title;
    }

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->data = array();
        $this->data['name'] = $name;
    }
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }

        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error('Undefined property via __get(): '. $name .' in '. $trace[0]['file'] .' on line' . $trace[0]['line'], E_USER_NOTICE);
        return null;
    }
    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->data[$name]);
    }
    public function __unset($name) {
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }
}
```

here is my render method on my response class:

```
public static function render($view) {
  include_once SITE_PATH .'app/views/layouts/root.layout.php');
}
```

called from one of my controllers...
the param $view is a simple View object...

Here is my root.layout.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title><?php $view->print_title(); ?></title>
</head>

<body>
 root layout
</body>
</html>
```

It seems i can't access to the $view object from the layout file included, may be a silly question, but right now i really can't realize why should not work...

Could someone explain me how php work in that situation? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually pass something, when you cann `render()`. Note, that you have a syntax error too.

Comment: Question edited with the full code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `include` instead of `include_once`, since your method can be called several times and it would work only the first ("once") time.

The PHP documentation says about the [scope of include](http://php.net/manual/function.include.php) (and also include_once):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the **variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs**. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

Therefor everything should work with your passed `$view` variable.

There is also a [nice example](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php) (the first one on the page) which explains that any variable available in the line before including will be available in the included file.